# ClassNotFoundException with SIGAR API

Tags: classnotfoundexception, sigar

I'm trying to work with the SIGAR API, and I added the external jar "sigar.jar" to my Build Path eclipse project. 
It compiles with no problem, but when I try to run the main class, that only does :

Cpu cpu = new Cpu();

it gives me this error:

```
    [java] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hyperic/sigar/Cpu
 [java]     at pt.client.User.main(User.java:90)
 [java] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hyperic.sigar.Cpu
 [java]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
 [java]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 [java]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
 [java]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
 [java]     at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
 [java]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
 [java]     ... 1 more
 [java] Java Result: 1
```

What may be missing?

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed to include `.so` file specific for your platform.

These files are located `../hyperic-sigar-folder/sigar-bin/lib`.

For example, if you are running under Linux 32 Bit, you have to include the file `libsigar-x86-linux.so` into your class-path as well.